# Not able to shorten tableView correctly on keyboard shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

- I have a tableView 10 rows with labels and textfields
- Every row is custom created based on indexPath
- I have a **UITextView** on 10th row
- I am trying to shorten and move table view up when textView is selected and keyboard is shown

I do:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    self.frame=CGRectMake(0,66,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight - 250);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
}
```

The tableView does move but the rows appear distorted. Meaning I see rows in following sequence:

- Row 8
- Row 9
- Row 2    // UNEXPECTED and DISTORTED
- Row 10

I did check cellforIndexPath for *Row 2* was not called when tableView was moved.

I wish I could show you.

Anything you could suggest?

**EDIT:**

Not sure but it looks like the issue is due to reuse of cells. The distorted cell was reused. If I set and check cell tag and do the following

```
[[cell.contentView subviews]
 makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

it seems to work. If anyone could suggest anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the `contentInset` instead of the frame. Your `UITableView` won't be shorter, but the content will not be hidden by the keyboard.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 250, 0)];
```